# How to repair bootloader

Tags: windows-8, grub, bootloader

To make a long story short; I installed some linux (pear 8), couldn't run it for some reason (error from the grub loader), then, I couldn't start windows 8.1 also, some error message.
I used bootrepair from linux live disc, but now I can't do anything! When I boot my computer it says 'No operating system found'...

I have a Windows 8 install disk, but the bcdedit can't open my data store.
I can't fix that either, because diskpart can only find my hard drive when I use it and type:
sel disk 0, then list vol..
When I use list part, I can see my windows 8 part (part 3, dynamic) but when I use sel part 3, it says it is invalid..
EDIT:
After some further research, Windows recovery says the whole disk is invalid, and my bios tools say it passed all the tests..

I don't know what to do.. I'm lost..
Does anybody have a solution?
Oh, maybe someone could use this: http://paste.ubuntu.com/6635374/

Comment: Was the Windows booting by legacy or UEFI?

Comment: I think legacy, because I installed it on a laptop that had windows 7 pre-installed

Comment: I think I'm going to reinstall windows and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

try booting from the install disk and choosing `Next -> Repair Computer -> Troubleshoot -> Advanced -> Command Prompt`

and then do following steps

1. `bootrec /fixmbr`
2. `bootrec /fixboot`
3. **Edit:** `bootrec /rebuildbcd` to scan for more OSs

this should fix your Master Boot Record and install the windows Bootloader again.

**Further Edit:** You can manually install the Boot Record with this:

1. `bootsect /nt60 c: /force /mbr` Write a new Bootsector to c: (or any other disc you prefer)
2. `bcdboot c:\windows /s c:` write a new Bootloader to `C:` pointing to the windows install at `c:\windows`

Comment: I already tried that. It can't find my os.

Comment: i edited my answer, see if that helps