# Windows XP bootloader issues

Tags: windows, windows-xp, bootloader, mbr

[How to repair bootloader](https://superuser.com/questions/692982/how-to-repair-bootloader)

I was looking through this post and feel like this is the process I need to be following.  I'm working with Windows XP and need to rebuild the "BOOT.INI" after deleting it.  Can anyone translate the steps over to Windows XP from Windows 8?

I'm trying "BOOTCFG /REBUILD" but it can't find my Windows installation for some reason.  I think this other thread may be the way to "manually" do so, but I need the correct DOS command for Windows XP.  If you have another suggestion for rebuilding my "BOOT.INI", I'm all ears!

Here's what I used initially to get to the point of deleting the "BOOT.INI":

http://icrontic.com/article/repair_windows_xp

Answer (score 1):

Boot to your XP CD and go through the repair options to choose the commamd prompt repair options ("Recovery Console").

type `fixboot` press enter
type `fixmbr` press enter

restart the machine and see if that fixes your install.

Only if the system partition wasn't found should you then try `bootcfg /rebuild`

Comment: I've long since tried the fixboot and fixmbr deal.  I'm now at the point of bootcfg /rebuild, although, I honestly don't think I should be doing any of them.  Up until the point where I deleted the boot.ini, I'm fairly certain everything was fine.  My problem at this point is I feel like the Motherboard is keeping me from booting.  It's like it is dead set on finding Grub now and won't look for anything else.

Comment: What response did you get from bootcfg /rebuild?

Comment: Try the lat steps of the following URL (at the bootcfg step): http://pcsupport.about.com/od/fixtheproblem/ht/repairbootini.htm

Comment: "BOOTCFG /REBUILD" didn't find any OS to mess with, so I never got to rebuild the "BOOT.INI" which doesn't seem to matter too much so long as I leave the Windows XP CD in the computer.  It boots from the XP SSD without any problems as long as it sees the DVD drive first with the disk.  Otherwise, if I just ask it to boot from the SSD, it won't see the OS.

Comment: I followed a guide similar to that one, but it didn't succeed with the "BOOTCFG /REBUILD", so I can't follow the final steps.  I need to manually create the "BOOT.INI" to finish this process and that's the part I don't know how to do.  Thanks for the link though!

Comment: Ok. You may want to try to build your own boot.ini file. This link http://homepage.ntlworld.com/mosaddique/Boot%20INI%20Sample%20files.html has some sample ones but you will need to edit the disks and OS title to match yours. The very first one on that site should be OKif you change the OS description to match yours.